# Use Play Framework library in an existing Scala Project

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I'm currently working on a Scala project, recently, I want to include some Play framework features to my project. As I'm using `sbt`, I change my build.sbt to:

```
import play.Project._

name := "deploymentmanager"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

playScalaSettings
```

project.sbt is also updated:

```
// The Typesafe repository 
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.2")
```

With those changes, I manage to build my project with Play's feature in it. However, when I'm writing code in Eclipse, all Play's features are marked as error: `not found, object play`. I wonder if there is any way to make Eclipse aware of Play library using sbt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the Eclipse sbt plugin. 
https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse

And then do a >eclipse from the command line to regenerate the Eclipse specific files and import/reload that project in Eclipse.